# How to send array object input to firestore on Angular?

Tags: arrays, json, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm just learning angular and trying to make a to-do-list app. I'm trying to send array object data to firestore. I have an array object input like this:

```
[
  {
    "isChecked": true
    "title": "Todo 1",
    
  },
  {
    "isChecked": true,
    "title": "Todo 2"
  }
]
```

I want to enter that into the input field. And here is my input field:

```html
<form action="" #importForm="ngForm (ngSubmit)="importJson(importForm, $event)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea ngModel name="importjson" #importjson="ngModel" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="10" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" >Ok</button>
</form>
```

And this is my app component :

```js
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { TodolistService } from '../../services/todolist.service';
import { Todolist } from '../../model/todolist.model';

export class TodolistComponent implements OnInit {

importjson: Todolist={};

constructor(private todolistService: TodolistService) { }

  @ViewChild('editTitle', {static: false}) input: ElementRef;
  ngOnInit(): void{

    this.todolistService.getToDoList().subscribe(items => {
      this.todos = items;
    })
  }
  
    importJson(importForm: FormGroup, submit){
    console.log(importForm.value.importjson);
    this.todolistService.addImport(importForm.value.importjson);
    this.importState = false;
  }
}
```

And here is my app service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from '@angular/fire/database' ;
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection, AngularFirestoreDocument } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Todolist } from '../model/todolist.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TodolistService {
  itemsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Todolist>;
  items: Observable<Todolist[]>;
  itemDoc: AngularFirestoreDocument<Todolist>;

  constructor(private firebasedb: AngularFireDatabase, public firestore: AngularFirestore) {
    this.itemsCollection = this.firestore.collection('titles');
    this.items = this.itemsCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions =>  actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Todolist;
        data.id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return data;
      }))
    );
   }

  addImport(item: Todolist) {
    this.itemsCollection.add(item);
  }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Just so I can understand better what you want to achieve, You want the form to add another object into the list? Each of those objects on the list represent a document in your Firestore, right?

Comment: Yes, right. @RafaelLemos

Comment: And `importForm.value.importjson` represents a single new Todo item or multiple items?

Comment: It represents new Todo multiple items.

Comment: Can you share the Todolist model as well?